For a given directed acyclic graph G, how can I best create a list of all new edges which would keep the graph acyclic?
I have a directed acyclic graph G. I want to generate some data structure which would tell me which new given edges (u,v) would be allowed while keeping the graph acyclic.
For example, given the graph G ([A,B,C,D]) on the left, I want to generate the graph G_ ([A_,B_,C_,D_]) on the right, which contains all single new edges which would be allowed:

Of course, the graph G_ is itself cyclic, but each individual edge in G_ could be added to G alone without making G cyclic. Each time a new edge is added to G, I will recompute G_. Duplicate edges are allowed in G.
My first approach is the following:

Generate the transitive closure of the graph

Transpose the transitive closure. Let's call this G_t

For each vertex u, get a list of its adjacent vertices in G_t. This list of vertices essentially tells me all the vs for which (u,v) would cause a cycle. Let's call this list u_

Perform a difference of all vertices minus u_. The result is a list of all vs for which (u,v) is allowed.


I'm wondering if a) this is the best method and b) if this method/resulting graph already has a given name or is already known and encompassed in a single algorithm.
For context, the graph is likely to have between 10-100 vertices.

I commend you for writing an excellent question, with thoughtful implementation ideas and - even better - a good example.

The transitive closure is all you need. If you are trying to add a new edge, say (a,b), to the original graph, just check if there is (b,a) in the transitive closure.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Unfortunately I need to keep a data structure which has all possible edges, rather than only checking for validity when a new edge is trying to be added. I guess a brute force attempt along those lines is to make a second graph with all the same vertices, then loop through every possible edge (a,b), and only add it if (b,a) is not in the transitive closure. I just wonder if this is not as efficient as other solutions regarding graphs with dozens or hundreds of vertices

The reason for the above is that for each vertex V, I need to present a list of valid edges which could be sourced from V.

Representing your graph as an adjacency matrix does all you need. Your lists are matrix columns (or rows), possibly inverted.

@n.m.couldbeanAI I'm not sure that's correct. Whether represented as an adjacency_list or an adjacency_matrix, the operations needed are transitive closure, then complement, then transposition. That result would then have each row being the desired list per vertex

Yes that's exactly correct. Transitive closure is a variation of matrix multiplication.

You could detect prohibited back edges using a regular depth-first-search, much in the way that topological sort detects the not_a_dag() exception.
Going by the documented pseudo code you should be able to harvest adjacencies with GRAY vertex coloring in finish_vertex:

Here's how I'd implement the visitor to do that:
template <typename ColorMap> struct Visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    Visitor(G& out, ColorMap cmap) : _out(out), _cmap(cmap) {}

    void finish_vertex(V u, G const& g) const {
        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
            if (v == u)
                continue;
            if (get(_cmap, v) == Color::gray())
                continue;

            // if (auto existing = edge(u, v, g).second; !existing)
            add_edge(u, v, _out);
        }
    }

    using Color = boost::color_traits<typename boost::property_traits<ColorMap>::value_type>;
    G&       _out;
    ColorMap _cmap;
};

Now you can create the complementary graph with e.g.:
G dag_extensions(G const& g) {
    G result; // (num_vertices(g));

    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> color(num_vertices(g));
    depth_first_search(g, visitor(Visitor(result, color.data())).vertex_color_map(color.data()));

    return result;
}

Live Demo
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/transform_value_property_map.hpp>

using G = boost::adjacency_list<>;
using V = boost::graph_traits<G>::vertex_descriptor;
using E = boost::graph_traits<G>::edge_descriptor;
enum { A, B, C, D };
static std::string get_vertex_label(size_t i) { return std::string(1, 'A' + i); };

template <typename ColorMap> struct Visitor : boost::default_dfs_visitor {
    Visitor(G& out, ColorMap cmap) : _out(out), _cmap(cmap) {}

    void finish_vertex(V u, G const& g) const {
        for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
            if (v == u)
                continue;
            if (get(_cmap, v) == Color::gray())
                continue;

            // if (auto existing = edge(u, v, g).second; !existing)
            add_edge(u, v, _out);
        }
    }

    using Color = boost::color_traits<typename boost::property_traits<ColorMap>::value_type>;
    G&       _out;
    ColorMap _cmap;
};

G dag_extensions(G const& g) {
    G result; // (num_vertices(g));

    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> color(num_vertices(g));
    depth_first_search(g, visitor(Visitor(result, color.data())).vertex_color_map(color.data()));

    return result;
}

static auto names(G const& g) {
    return make_transform_value_property_map(+get_vertex_label, get(boost::vertex_index, g));
};

static void dot(std::string fname, G& g) {
    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", names(g));
    std::ofstream ofs(fname);
    write_graphviz_dp(ofs, g, dp, "node_id");
};

int main() {
    boost::adjacency_list<> g(4);

    add_edge(A, B, g);
    add_edge(A, C, g);
    add_edge(C, D, g);

    dot("graph.dot", g);
    print_graph(g, names(g));

    auto complement = dag_extensions(g);
    dot("complement.dot", complement);
    print_graph(complement, names(complement), std::cout << "\ncomplement:\n");
}

Printing
A --> B C 
B --> 
C --> D 
D --> 

complement:
A --> B C D
B --> C D
C --> B D
D --> B

And writing the following dots:



Original
Complement










Several of the steps (especially if you want to exclude existing edges) will be more efficient with an adjacency_matrix

Ah this is a super interesting solution. I need to spend some time fully understanding it, but thank you so much for your clarity. I spent the rest of my day starting to implement my initial idea, which I think formally is the transposition of the complement of the transitive closure. Boost gives me transpose and transitive closure, so I was trying to find a way to cheaply negate the result of an "if_edge_exists" check on a given graph, to produce the complement.
I think transitive closure would internally run a DFS (?) anyway, so I think your approach in the end would have less complexity

Regarding the adjacency_matrix, I will investigate this too. It's actually a requirement that existing edges are included, so that point isn't an issue for my use case, but good to know in general

Unfortunately I think there is a problem with this solution if the DAG is not a tree. For example if there was an edge (B, D) added, then the resulting graph would have an erroneous edge (D,C). But I do like the direction this is going and will continue to try to find a way around this problem

Another issue is if the DFS does not start at the root of the graph, for example if there was a vertex E and an edge (E,A).

@rbv Good points. I get the issue with BD added. I'm not sure I see the problem with non-root starts: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cab959af69389e2e see the outputs side-by-side: https://imgur.com/a/mes6wBk

I think the change of if (get(_cmap, v) == Color::gray()) to if (get(_cmap, v) != Color::black()) fixes the non-root starts errors which I noticed before - if you revert that check then you'll see that when the DFS starts with A, there are erroneous edges whose target is E in the "nonroot" case. So while that line change fixes the "nonroot" case, it seems to break the "simple" case: simple-complementA.png and simple-complementE.png have different results

The line change also seems to fix the "nontree" issue from before but introduces a new one: the result is missing the edge (B,C). Still, I want to say again that I appreciate your work and it's definitely pointing me in a very good direction, I will continue to attempt to solve these further cases too!

Oh darn. I forgot I tried that change :) Sorry. But yeah, it helps in the end. Is the "simple" difference not merely due to the fact that E is not connected? It could be easy to detect - especially for bidirectionalS models

Yeah it think it is due to the fact that E is not connected. In the real case I'm dealing with, it could be that the input graph is made up of several unconnected subgraphs, and even some unconnected vertices, so I do need to consider that case too. I think I can limit the inputs to being only bidirectionalS models

Do you want to accept new edges that connect between components? I guess if this is some kind of UI editor that allows you to add vertices before connecting them, the answer is going to be yes.

Yes, essentially what I want to provide is a dropdown on each vertex U, which lists all of the other vertices V for which (U,V) would be allowed. Selecting one of the elements of that dropdown would then add that edge. And yes you can add vertices before connecting them

I've found a solution based on your initial answer (with the == gray check) which seems to work for all of my test cases, but I'm not sure it's terribly efficient. Basically first doing a transitive closure pass, then feeding that into the DFS from your answer. The visitor's finish_vertex needs a new check if (get(_cmap, v) == Color::white() && edge(v,u,g).second) continue. Essentially saying that if we're looking from a black u node to a white v, only add (u,v) if there is no (v,u) in the transitive closure. Not sure on the efficiency but it does seem to work
